# ASP.NET bundling and minification. Runs once per request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am wondering how may times the bundling and minification runs on the server?

Is it once per HTML request?
Once per browser session?
Once every time the app gets deployed?

Comment: Every time the app pool recycles

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bundles are created when the application is deployed or restarted, when the `Application_Start` method is called in `Global.asax.cs`. Inside `Application_Start`, `BundleConfig.RegisterBundles` is invoked, which is actually where the magic happens.

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    // this method is called on application start
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas(); // registers areas
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters); // registers filters
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes); // registers routes
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles); // this generates the bundles
    }
}
```

And in your `BundleConfig.cs` file, the `RegisterBundles` method is the method that is called to create said bundles.

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        // this is actually what's creating the bundles
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
        // etc...
    }
}
```

They are then cached in memory, can be accessed at `/bundles/bundlename?v=versionId`, and *served* for each HTTP request, but the actual process of bundling and minification only happens once.

Answer (score 2):

*bundling* and *minification* registered with **Application_Start** runs once and result is cached on server. Cached version provides for other request. Aplication_Start fires when first resource requested.